# Easiest Way To CC multiple emails for all incoming mail to Gmail

Tags: email, gmail

I have a WordPress site (hosted on WordPress) setup to automatically forward emails to `email@mydomain.com` to a Gmail address I setup, `email@gmail.com`. I would like to CC any incoming mail to a list of addresses.

I work on a condo board and my intention is to have one address where a resident can send an email to that automatically gets forwarded to all members of the board.

I discovered you can forward emails via filters to a single address, but I have not seen a mechanism to automatically get everyone included on the same forward email.

Is there any better way to do things like this? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3):

The best and most flexible way to do this may be to create a classic email list. Since you mentioned Gmail in your question, we can keep it in the Google ecosystem by creating our email list with Google Groups. Visit the [Google Groups signup page](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!creategroup) and enter an email address for your email list (like `example@googlegroups.com`).

During sign-up, you should:

- Add all the email addresses of the condo board members
- Select "All members of the group" for who can view topics
- Select "Anyone on the web" for who can post
- Select "Only invited users" for who can join, if you want it to only be the board members - or "Anyone can ask" if you want residents to be able to ask to become recipients too (if it's more of a community list).

After sign-up, you should:

- Forward emails from `condoboard@example.com` to `example@googlegroups.com`, using the google groups email address you chose at sign up.

To the best of my knowledge, the workflow would then be like this:

1. Resident sends email to your custom domain.
2. Email arrives at the google groups address and is forwarded to all board members.
3. Board members can discuss the email among themselves by replying to it, and Google Groups forwards their replies to all board members (but not the resident).
4. When a board member is ready to reply to the resident, they click reply on the resident's original email, but also add the resident in the "To" field, so that it goes to the resident in addition to the rest of the board members.

To be honest I don't have a lot of experience with Google Groups so am not entirely sure this setup will work the way you want it to, or quite as I described - it's just an idea that you would need to test out. My second thought is to go whole hog and use a  customer service ticketing system - but maybe that would make it feel too corporate?

Comment: I'm fine with a ticketing system. Do you know of any wordpress plugins that do that?

Comment: @thatidiotguy FreshDesk is reputable, and they have a free plan and a WordPress plugin.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done for multiple email addresses. 
Rather than recreate the wheel, there is a good article with screenshots on how to set this up on the makeuseof.com website:
[How to Auto-Forward Emails to Multiple Addresses in Gmail](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-auto-forward-emails-to-multiple-addresses-in-gmail/)

> From the page:
>   1) The first step is to set up the email forwarding.
>   Go to Settings > Forwarding and POP/IMAP. Click the Add a forwarding
>   address button. This will send an email to each address you wish to
>   automatically forward emails to with a confirmation link that has to
>   be clicked.   You will have to repeat this step for each email.
>   2)
>   Once each of the emails have been confirmed, you can create a filter
>   for the messages you want to forward. With the filter feature, you can
>   automatically forward emails with a specific subject line, from a
>   specific sender, or even messages with  specific keywords.   Under
>   Gmail’s Settings go to Filters and Blocked Addresses and click the
>   Create new filter button. You can fill in the details for the emails
>   you want to forward. Once you’ve filled it in, click Create filter
>   with this search.
>   3) The next step is to choose the emails you want to
>   forward the emails to. Make sure to check “Forward it” and from the
>   dropdown menu select the email addresses that have been confirmed.
>   Unfortunately, because of the way that Gmail forwarding works, you
>   will have to repeat this step each time for each email you want to
>   forward to.

Comment: Answers that have the key information behind a link can suffer from link rot which will make the answer worthless if that webpage goes away. Please quote the key information.

Comment: edited post to quote the key information

Comment: This does not do what I want however. Doesn't this forward to all the emails individually? I want gmail to forward the message to all the emails in one email (i.e. one person in To: field, rest in CC) so that if a recipient replies all it automatically goes to all the board members.

Comment: Ok, yeah i see what you mean, it can be setup to automatically forward, but only one at a time